# How to move boot loader from HDD to SDD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, ssd

I dual booted my ssd with windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04. Only after the installation was completed that I realized that both the boot loaders for windows and ubuntu are in the HDD instead of SSD. I guess it slows the boot time a bit (though it is still fast). Is it possible to transfer the boot loader to SSD from HDD now? or is there no need to do so?

ssd is UEFI install with gpt partitioned. The os files are in the ssd, but the boot loaders are in the HDD. Apparently it also seems that there are 2 windows boot loader. (Initially I had windows 10 in HDD, I formatted the drive. I guess I should have also formatted the boot manager partition separately as well then.)

```
  Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
  Partition Table: gpt
  Disk Flags: 

  Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                                    Flags
   1      1049kB  17.8MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
   2      17.8MB  103GB   102GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
   3      103GB   256GB   154GB   ext4


  Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ04ABF1 (scsi)
  Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
  Partition Table: gpt
  Disk Flags: 

  Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                             Flags
   1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
   2      106MB   123MB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
   3      123MB   838GB   838GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
   4      838GB   999GB   161GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
   5      999GB   1000GB  1074MB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
```

Comment: Did you not ask the exact same question yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

To move Windows 10 boot manager to SSD from the old HDD, you can try the software-AOMEI Partition Assistant, which can move Windows-related partitions including the boot manager to another drive and ensure you can boot from it without any problems.